# update a row in mysqli with if else statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table in my mysqli database without getting the data first...what i am looking to do is the following

```
Update Table set senta = 1 if playera = 12 else set sentb = 1 if playerb = 12 Limit 1
```

Comment: It's not clear, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: and here is me thinking that this is it's simplest form and even a baby could understand it....PAUL.....you let the team down paul!! lol

Comment: "Guessable" and "clear" is not the same. See: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pseudocode means the next code in SQL syntax

```sql
UPDATE `table`
SET senta = CASE WHEN playera = 12
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE senta
                 END,
    sentb = CASE WHEN playera != 12 AND playerb = 12
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE sentb
                 END
WHERE 12 IN (playera, playerb)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: cheers this is exactly what I am looking for, first time doing if statement in mysqli